# ICollection<T> where T implements an interface

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
public interface ISomething
{
}

public class SomethingThatImplementsISomething: ISomething
{
}

public class SomethingElse
{
 public ICollection<ISomething> PropertyName{ get; set; }
}
```

I've tried it out, and it keeps failing. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps failing"?

Comment: It ..doesn't work. It says that I can't pass the class that implements the interface into a new instance of the collection. But making the property an ICollection<T> lets me instantiate anything that implements ICollection, like List, etc. I don't see why it can't work for the generic type within the collection.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic type within the collection"? `ISomething` is not a generic type.

Comment: -1 - Why does everyone have to guess what the problem is? Post a full question with enough information so that people can answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ICollection<Models.Awardable>` can *not* be converted to `ICollection<IAwardable>`.

What would happen if someone tried to add an `IAwardable` to the collection that *wasn't* a `Models.Awardable`?

Just instantiate a collection of `IAwardable` and add instances of `Models.Awardable` to it.

Comment: Oh dear, I feel so foolish. Such entry level C#, I was so caught up by the error I neglected to realize that the interface abstraction was precisely the reason I wanted it to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that in C# 4, you will be able to convert IEnumerable<Awardable> to IEnumerable<IAwardable>, but NOT ICollection<Awardable> to ICollection<IAwardable>. The difference being: since you cannot add things to an IEnumerable, the objection about adding goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `using System.Collections.Generic` rather than just `using System.Collections` at the top of your compilation unit.

Edited to add:

Actually, this probably has to do with the fact that version of C# prior to 4.0 do not allow for covariance or contravariance for generics. In older versions, a generic field must be defined to use an exact data type, to avoid invalid reference type assignments.

Edited again:

Now that I see the actual error message that you are getting, the problem is not in the definition of the field, but in its use. You need to put an explicit cast in the assignment.

Comment: I've tried this a few times, but I guess the syntax is strange within a generic. How can I do an explicit cast within the generic declaration?

Answer (score 1):

The auto-property

```
 public ICollection<ISomething> PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

tries to create a backing-field of type `ICollection<>`, which will fail. Try something like:

```
 public List<ISomething> PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Why would that fail?  It's perfectly okay to have a backing field/autoprop of type `ICollection<Whatever>`.  You just have to remember to set it to something (which will indeed have to be a concrete type such as `List<Whatever>`) before using it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm setting it to a List<T> upon instantiation, and passing through a Type that implements the interface. Still no go. I've got the proper namespaces declared in my file.

Comment: Nope, it is initialized as null. Initialization can be overwritten in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is this:

```
ICollection<SomethingThatImplementsISomething> collection = new List<SomethingThatImplementsISomething>();
somethingElse.PropertyName = collection;
```

If that's the case, then this is a [generic variance](http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2008/12/c-covariance-and-contravariance-by-example.html) issue.  ICollection is not covariant in its element type.  (Because it it were, you could now go `somethingElse.PropertyName.Add(somethingDifferentThatsAlsoAnISomething);` -- and you'd have added a SomethingDifferentThatsAlsoAnISomething to a list of SomethingThatImplementsISomething, which breaks type safety.)

You need to instantiate a collection of ISomethings:

```
ICollection<ISomething> collection = new List<ISomething>();
somethingElse.PropertyName = collection;
```

You can then add SomethingThatImplementsISomething objects to your heart's content:

```
somethingElse.PropertyName.Add(new SomethingThatImplementsISomething());
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I forgot that the generic type is just that, a type, not an object. I was trying to instantiate the generic using a class that implemented the interface, rather than instantiate with the interface and assign objects of classes that implemented it. I understand where the error is, now.